# Testing en Golang, covertura en diferentes carpetas

Tags: test, go

tengo un paquete de pruebas en un proyecto de Go con la siguiente estructura:

|_ tests 
   |_ test_clientes
       |_ archivo_test.go
       |_ archivo2_test.go
   |_ test_usuarios
       |_archivo_test.go
       |_archivo2_test.go
   controller_test.go

Estando dentro de test, cuando ejecuto el siguiente comando:
go test ./... -coverpkg=../...
De esta manera al ejecutar ese comando, para controller_test.go el coverpkg=./... hace referencia al proyecto y los testing que estan dentro de las carpetas se ejecutan correctamente, pero calculan la covertura en la carpeta test, cómo podría hacer que la covertura se calcule por la referencia del controller_test.go, muchas gracias.

Comment: Cómo se llama el paquete del controller que estás testeando?

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de entender bien tu pregunta, pero si lo que quieres es ejecutar solo los test de `controller_test.go` puedes hacer:

```
$ go test controller_test.go ./ruta/a/controller.go -coverprofile=coverage.out
```

esto asume que los dos ficheros están en el mismo `package`

También puedes ejecutar los test individualmente:

```
$ go test nombreDelPackage -run NombreDelTest -coverprofile=coverage.out
```

Si está respuesta no te ayuda por favor edita tu pregunta para clarificar mejor que es lo que quieres.